# Yesod sanitizing quotation marks in Javascript / Julius

Tags: javascript, haskell, yesod, sanitization

I'm having a little bit of trouble including Javascript into my Yesod application. The issue is that everything that I try to include with `toWidget` is getting HTML-sanitized. Here is how my edited `Foundation.hs` looks:

```
defaultLayout widget = do
     master <- getYesod
     mmsg <- getMessage

     pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
         $(widgetFile "default-layout")
         toWidget someJs
```

where in another imported module

```
someJs = [julius| "foo stuff"; |]
```

which generates code that looks like

```
<script>&quot;foo stuff&quot;;</script>
```

I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening. Is there a Julius-specific `toWidget` I could use? Is it `PageContent`'s fault? Any help with this would be tremendous. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this out in the scaffolded site, by commenting out the `addStaticContent` method, and couldn't reproduce the problem. Can you provide some runnable code that results in this output?

Comment: Sure thing! I just tried commenting out `addStaticContent` as well, with some even more interesting results. The javascript I'm trying to include is [GSAP](https://github.com/athanclark/gsap-shakespeare) (you can find my wrapper code under `haskell/`, it's really simple. I'd like to keep the term aliases instead of static `.julius` files, though, to add parametricity later for customization), and my lightly edited [Foundation.hs](http://lpaste.net/109789#line78). Here are a [couple screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/YRdtG) of the strange inclusion, too. Thank you for responding so quickly!!

Comment: Where is tween lite defined?

Comment: Right [here](https://github.com/athanclark/gsap-shakespeare/blob/master/haskell/Web/JavaScript/GSAP.hs#L7) (sorry). It's just a dummy wrapper around the original GSAP code.

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce this issue. I'd really need a piece of code I can run to be able to move forward with helping on this.

Comment: This is turning out to be a strange issue. I at first simply added `Web/JavaScript/GSAP.hs` module to the working directory, and used the same `Foundation.hs` code as before, but the javascript wasn't even included. So I've found that you __must__ clone my [GSAP](https://github.com/athanclark/gsap-shakespeare) repository, compile it as a sandbox, and include it as a dependency via `cabal sandbox add-source` to [this](https://github.com/athanclark/yesod-issue-javascript.git) project. Only then, was I able to duplicate the error. [Here](http://deconfigured.com) is a live example.